# Apache POI, creating new cells overrides the row style

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm using Apache POI to export data to a .xlsx file and I want to style some of the rows and cells contained in the file.

I'm using XSSF since the file is going to be read in Excel 2007+.

Basically, my problem is that I'm trying to set a row style like in the following example, which sets a black foreground color for the entire row at index 0. It works fine, but whenever I create a new cell, the newly created cell has no style, as if it's overriding the row style I specified.

Here's a code snippet to demonstrate what I'm doing:

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("mySheet");
XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);

XSSFCellStyle myStyle = wb.createCellStyle();           

myStyle.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(new Color(255, 255, 255)));
myStyle.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

row.setRowStyle(myStyle); //This works, the whole row is now black

row.createCell(0); // This cell doesn't have a style, the rest of the line stays stylized
row.getCell(0).setCellValue("Test");
```

I also tried *row.createCell(0, Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);*, but it didn't change anything.

What is the correct way of accomplishing what I want to do? I wanted to do it this way so I didn't have to set each cell's style after creating it since all cells on the same row have the same style.

Comment: try calling _row.createCell()_ before  _row.setRowStyle(myStyle);_

Comment: Yeah I already tried that and the order does't matter it seems

Comment: _row.setCellValue("Test");_ gives me a compile time error check!

Comment: @BhavikShah This is an error when I made this example for my post, see the updated question

Comment: more than 7 years later the setRowStyle still doesn't work in an intuitive way :D I am having the same issue right now and it bothers me that setRowStyle doesn't provide a default value for the cells in that row (even if set after cell creation)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set the style into newly created cell as well e.g. below:

```
    XSSFCell newCell = row.createCell(0);
    newCell.setCellStyle(myStyle);
```

Comment: I know I can do that as I mentioned in my question, but I don't really see what the point of setting the row style is if I have to manually set each cell's style afterwards anyway.

Comment: @AdamSmith: I doubt if the newly created cell inherits the properties from parent.

Comment: I guess I'll have to do it this way then. I thought it worked like when I do it manually in Excel (set a color for the whole row, then when you put data in a cell the style stays). Thanks for your answer! I guess what I'm asking is just not possible.

Comment: @adam-smith Assuming `setRowStyle` works the same as `setDefaultColumnStyle`: This actually sets the (default) style for cells that are added manually  *after the workbook has been exported already* (i.e. by a human).

Answer (score 10):

Even you create a row with style, it will not effect to created cell of its. The create cell have their own cell style.
The `row style` will not override to `cell style` automatically. If you would like use row style in cell, you have to set again.

Even if you set `row style` at end, it will not effect to cell.

Example

```
CreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("new sheet");
Row r = sheet.createRow(0);
r.setRowStyle(rowStyle);

Cell c1 = r.createCell(0);
c1.setCellValue("Test 1");
c1.setCellStyle(rowStyle);
```

Comment: @mateus-viccari Assuming `setRowStyle` works the same as `setDefaultColumnStyle`: This actually sets the (default) style for cells that are added manually  *after the workbook has been exported already* (i.e. by a human).

Answer (score 2):

I'm agree that "setRowStyle" doesn't work as it should be.

I created my own function to apply a style to a range ( could be a row or multiple row )

```
public void applyStyleToRange(Sheet sheet, CellStyle style, int rowStart, int colStart, int rowEnd, int colEnd) {
    for (int r = rowStart; r <= rowEnd; r++) {
        for (int c = colStart; c <= colEnd; c++) {
            Row row = sheet.getRow(r);

            if (row != null) {
                Cell cell = row.getCell(c);

                if (cell != null) {
                    cell.setCellStyle(style);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```